# How to resolve error in Vuetify rules [v-text-field] & computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

If I add rules into all my fields -> error rule. 
But if I don't add rules on any fields -> no rules error. 
My VueAppProject is running ok, but this error on console means something.

Error:

```
Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'undefined' instead
found in ---> <VTextField>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox or codepen so we can reproduce your issue? It's kind of difficult to debug the issue without seeing your <template> section and just on a screenshot

Comment: dude i created my first codepen xd, but i couldn't sho.w my app.. this is the code: https://codepen.io/Gonzalo_gg/pen/vYNByvZ so if you see the error in this project , tell me please

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be its because you're not qualifying the name of your Rules object - you're asking Vuetify to find a rule called 'required' = but you have nothing in your data() with that name, you have an object called 'mixinsRules' and that in turn has a function called 'required'.

Try qualifying the reference to 'required' with the name of its parent object, like this:

```
{
    field:    'email',
    //...
    rules: '[mixinsRules.required]'
}
```